# Incorrect Answer Trying to Find Hamming Distance

Tags: algorithms, hamming-code

```
A 010101
B 110011
C 111000
D 000111
```

The minimum Hamming distance of those code words is 3 as the minimum difference is 3 but the correct answer is 2.

How can I find the correct Hamming distance?

Answer (score 1):

- A 0**1**01**0**1
- D 0**0**01**1**1

There are two bits different (namely the bold ones). So the hamming distance is 2.